# Density Plot in 3D

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following code:

```
gxx = -n^2*\[Alpha]^2*(kx^2 + ky^2)^(
   n - 2)*(kx^2*kz^2*vz^2 + 
      ky^2*(kz^2*vz^2 + (kx^2 + ky^2)^n*\[Alpha]^2))/(4*(kz^2*
         vz^2 + (kx^2 + ky^2)^n*\[Alpha]^2)^(5/2));

n = 1; vz = 1; \[Alpha] = 0.5; (*n=1 or 2 or 3; \[Alpha]= 0.5 or 1 or 2*)

DensityPlot3D[gxx, {kx, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {kz, -\
\[Pi], \[Pi]}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\)]\)", Large], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(y\)]\)", Large], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(z\)]\)", Large]}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

The 3D plot is completely red and uses only a tiny portion of available colors. Also I can't really see what it looks like towards the centre, is there a way we can solve the above problems and also make the graph look prettier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expression obtains a large range of values and it blows up near the origin, therefore you need to do some clipping. The representation should depend on the features you want to emphasize.

If you want to show what happens near the boundary, you can cut out a chunk from the interior:

```
region = RegionDifference[Cube[2 \[Pi]], Cube[6]];
DensityPlot3D[gxx, {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] region, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 AxesLabel -> {"kx", "ky", "kz"}, OpacityFunction -> .2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To emphasize the divergence at the origin, you can use `ClipPlanes` to better see inside, together with `PlotRange` to cut off the divergence.

```
DensityPlot3D[gxx, {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] Cube[2 \[Pi]], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 20, 
 AxesLabel -> {"kx", "ky", "kz"}, 
 PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Full, {-10, 2}}, 
 ClipPlanes -> {-1, 0, 0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This still looks a bit weird. To emphasize the wide range of values, you can instead plot in the logarithmic color scale:

```
DensityPlot3D[Log@Abs@gxx, {kx, ky, kz} \[Element] Cube[2 \[Pi]], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 AxesLabel -> {"kx", "ky", "kz"}, 
 PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Full, {-6.5, 5}}, 
 ClipPlanes -> {-1, 0, 0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lastly, you can make your representation slightly nicer if you use `SliceDensityPlot3D`.

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[gxx, {"BackPlanes", 
  Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 
   2]}, {kx, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {kz, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {"kx", "ky", "kz"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for such a great insight. It serves my purpose.